# Independence of Gaussian Distribution Function with Different Means

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Is there any way to prove that $N$ Gaussian distribution functions are linearly independent if and only if the means are different. For example, if
f1(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp{\frac{-(x-\mu1)^2}{2\sigma^2}
\vdots
fN(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp{\frac{-(x-\muN)^2}{2\sigma^2}
$f_1,...,f_N$ they are all linearly independent iff the means $(\mu_1, ... ,\mu_N)$ are not equal.

Comment: What do you mean by linear independence of Gaussian distribution functions? That the densities, or cdf, are linearly independent? That the rv are linearly independent?

Comment: I mean the densities f1...fN when you look at them as a function of a given RV lets say x. Are f1(x)... fN(x) LI iff the means are different

Comment: Linearly independent over what? The densities of the standard normal and the normal with mean $0$ and variance $4$ are linearly independent over the reals.

Comment: They are not linear independent functions because you can find c for which f1+cf2=0

Comment: You cannot. The second has density of the shape $ke^{-x^2/8}$.

Comment: Right I should have said same variance with different means. f1 ... fn they all have the same variance

Answer (score 1):

Assume without loss of generality that $(\mu_n)$ is decreasing. The simplest approach could be to divide any null linear combination $\sum\limits_na_nf_n=0$ by the gaussian density with parameters $(0,\sigma^2)$, yielding $$\sum_na_n\exp(x\mu_n-\mu_n^2/2)=0.$$ When $x\to\infty$, every exponential term except the first one is negligible with respect to the first one since $\exp(x\mu_1)\gg\exp(x\mu_n)$ for every $n\ne1$, hence $a_1=0$. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Thanks but how do I show this is iff

Comment: You mean, you are unable to show that if mu_i=mu_j for some distinct i and j then the functions f_1, f_2, ..., f_N, are not linearly independent?

Comment: I mean can we say if they are linearly independent then mu_i is not equal to mu_j

Comment: Yes we can, because if mu_i=mu_j then they are linearly dependent (bis).