# Linear independence of PDFs

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request

Let's start with an

> **Example:** Consider the PDFs of a multivariate normal distribution and a multivariate Student distribution. How to prove that they are linearly independent, as functions from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$?

More generally, I'm interested in general proof strategies (or references!) on the following:

> **Question:** How to prove that a given set of PDFs is linearly independent? For example, under additional assumptions, e.g., unimodality and distinct modes.

To provide some motivation, I'm trying to understand better [strict linear independence of probability measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4849541/551592): probability measures $P_1, \dotsc, P_K$ defined on a space $\mathcal X$ are strictly linearly independent if for every vector $\lambda\neq 0$ there exists a measurable set $A$ such that
$$\lambda_1 P_1(A) + \cdots + \lambda_K P_K(A) \neq 0,$$
or, equivalently, $|\lambda_1 P_1 + \cdots + \lambda P_K|(\mathcal X) > 0$.

In case of $\mathcal X = \mathbb R^n$ and *continuous* PDFs $p_1, \dotsc, p_K$ this condition is equivalent to the linear independence of their PDFs.

The proof for exponential distributions with distinct rates is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451686/551592) and there exist proof strategies based on asymptotics for normal distributions (e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1081379/551592) or [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1087610/551592)).
However, I think more general results should follow, perhaps based on the notion of strict linear independence of measures. Intuitively, if I have several different unimodal distributions and a given $\lambda \neq 0$, then trying as the candidate set $A$ small balls centered around different modes, may work. However, I have not been able to formalise this argument.